# Get list of all users Logging in ADFS 2.0

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, adfs

I wish to know if there is a way to get a list of all the users Logging in and out of ADFS 2.0.
Is this possible. 
Regards

Answer (score 1):

You could enable auditing to have AD FS generate events for the token issuance. Does that meet your needs?

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/adfs2-troubleshooting-configuring-computers(v=WS.10).aspx#bkmk_ConfigureAuditing